# How to convert Oracle query to Postgresql Example some convert function not working Postgress

Tags: postgresql

```
select
    ID,
    LAST_NAME,
    FIRST_NAME,
    MI
from
    Table name
where
    REPORT_NO = 'some no'
    and CHANGE_IND is null
order by
        UPPER(convert(LAST_NAME, 'US7ASCII', 'AL14UTF8')),
        UPPER(convert(FIRST_NAME, 'US7ASCII', 'AL15UTF8')),
        UPPER(convert(MI, 'US7ASCII', 'AL15UTF8')),
        table name;
```

The above query is a oracle query How can I convert this into PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is that supposed to do? Converting from ASCII to UTF-8 is a no-operation.

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function convert(character varying, unknown, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 466                             => this error I m getting when I run this query. What should I do?

Comment: That is true. But we can only tell you how to translate that if we know what it does.